# Files not appearing in Jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins

I have an `npm` script that basically executes some unit tests with Jest and then generates a `test-results.xml` file in a `dist/` folder. This is executed within a `deploy.sh` script that basically has a `npm run test` line in it that kicks off the test task.

When Jenkins runs my code, however, I can see that the tests are passing in the Jenkins console, but for some reason Jenkins can't see the `test-results.xml` file in the workspace. Hence, I get this error:

```
ERROR: Step ‘Publish JUnit test result report’ failed: No test report files were found. Configuration error?
```

It's weird because I SSH'd into my server and can clearly see that my test script generated a `test-results.xml` file under `dist/` folder, but for some reason the entire `dist/` folder and everything in it is conspicuously absent from my Jenkins workspace.

Comment: What pattern have you entered into the Public JUnit test result report?

Comment: Hey! I just have it set to `dist/test-results.xml`

Comment: Yea, that should work. Maybe the format of the XML file is wrong?

Comment: Hmm, I took a look and it seems perfectly valid to me :O I do notice that I get an error like this though: `‘dist/test-results.xml’ doesn’t match anything: even ‘dist’ doesn’t exist` for some reason it can't find `dist/`

Comment: Okay, really strange. My only guess is that the workspace points to some other directory. In the beginning of the build there should be something in the lines of `Building remotely on Agent42 in workspace <path_to_workspaces>/workspace/<job_name>` in the console output. Can you verify that the path is the same as the one you are looking at when SSHing?

Comment: OMG, thank you.... that made it occur to me... my deploy script `ssh`'s into my remote server, so all the linting and unit testing is done on that remote machine... so none of those files are really on the Jenkins VM. *facepalm* Which makes me wonder... should I build the project on my Jenkins box, including testing and linting, and if it all passes, then publish via my ssh deploy script?

Comment: Good that you found the problem :) If you need to ssh into another server, then I would say that you should add that server as an Agent/slave to your Jenkins master, that way you can run builds there natively.

Comment: :D thanks! Yes that's what I did (I think). I added a post-build action that executes a `deploy` bash script which will ssh into the remote server and do the deployment, but the shell script will only be executed if the build succeeds. That way if a test or lint fails, the new code will never get deployed. This CD stuff is finally starting to make some sense!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*This question was resolved in question comments, but for future reference and other in similar situations:*

Make sure that you are looking at the same place as Jenkins is. Jenkins always resolves the pattern provided in the `Public JUnit test result report` relative the workspace root.

For freestyle jobs or node steps in pipeline jobs, the location of the workspace root is printed on the console output, look for:

```
Building in workspace <jenkins_root>\workspace\<job_name>
```

or

```
Building remotely on Agent42 in workspace <path_to_workspaces>/workspace/<job_name>
```

Comment: Is there no way to specific an alternative path to the job name?